# Line break in a table cell for a math equation?

Tags: tables, math-mode, vertical-alignment

In the middle of typing up an assessment and trying to work out how to get equations to work inside a table environment

```
\documentclass [11pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\begin{document}


\title{CSC3407 assessment one }
\author{My name My student number}
\date{09/03/2013}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\begin{landscape}

\section{Question 3}
Fill the answers in the blanks in the two tables below. You need to provide the working process for each answer.
\subsection{A}
The network mask that supports: 
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
       Classful Network & Required borrowed subnet bits & The mask that supports the required subnets \\ \hline
        100.0.0.0 & 12 & 8 bits for class A + 12 bits for subnet = $ 11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000 =1x2^7+1x2^6+1x2^5+1x2^4+1x2^3+1x2^2+1x2^1+1x2^0= 255$   \\ 

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The equation I need to split is  100.0.0.0 & 12 & 8 bits for class A + 12 bits for subnet = `$ 11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000 =1x2^7+1x2^6+1x2^5+1x2^4+1x2^3+1x2^2+1x2^1+1x2^0= 255$`   \

If I could get the 1x2^7 ... to sit below the binary rep that would make it really good.

Example

```
11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000
=1x2^7+1x2^6+1x2^5+1x2^4+1x2^3+1x2^2+1x2^1+1x2^0= 255$
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the issue as well `\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
       Classful Network & Required borrowed subnet bits & The mask that supports the required subnets \\ \hline
        100.0.0.0 & 12 & 8 bits for class A + 12 bits for subnet = $ 11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000$ \\ & &$=1x2^7+1x2^6+1x2^5+1x2^4+1x2^3+1x2^2+1x2^1+1x2^0= 255$   \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}`

Answer (score 8):

You can benefit from the `aligned` environment of `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\section{Question 3}

Fill the answers in the blanks in the two tables below. You need to 
provide the working process for each answer.

\subsection{A}
The network mask that supports:\\[\medskipamount]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Classful Network & 
  Required borrowed &
  The mask that supports \\
& subnet bits & the required subnets \\ 
\hline
100.0.0.0 & 
  12 &
  8 bits for class A${}+{}$12 bits for subnet%
    $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &=\mathtt{11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000} \\
    &=1x2^7+1x2^6+1x2^5+1x2^4+1x2^3\\
    &\qquad{}+1x2^2+1x2^1+1x2^0=255
    \end{aligned}$ \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]