# How to break math formula inside table?

Tags: tables, math-mode

There are some mathematical formulas in the table that don't automatic line break, resulting in poor display and `Overfull` warning. So, how to fix it?

Here is the latex minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% support for `\multirow` command
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

The following table lists the interval estimator of $ \mu_{1} - \mu_{2} $ and $ \sigma_{1}^{2} / \sigma_{2}^{2} $ with $ 1 - \alpha $ confidence interval.

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Interval estimator for difference of means and ratio of variance in two normal populations}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{unknown parameter} & $ 1 - \alpha $ confidence interval \tabularnewline
\hline
\multirow{2}*{$ \mu_{1} - \mu_{2} $} & $ \sigma_{1}^{2} $, $ \sigma_{2}^{2} $ known & $ \left( \overline{X} - \overline{Y} - U_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1}^{2}}{n_{1}} + \frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}}{n_{2}}}, \overline{X} - \overline{Y} + U_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1}^{2}}{n_{1}} + \frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}}{n_{2}}} \right) $ \tabularnewline
\cline{2-3}
 & $ \sigma_{1}^{2} $, $ \sigma_{2}^{2} $ unknown, but $ \sigma_{1}^{2} = \sigma_{2}^{2} $ & $ \left( \overline{X} - \overline{Y} - T_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} (n_{1} + n_{2} - 2) S_{\omega} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{1}} + \frac{1}{n_{2}}}, \overline{X} - \overline{Y} + T_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} (n_{1} + n_{2} - 2) S_{\omega} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{1}} + \frac{1}{n_{2}}} \right) $ \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$ \sigma_{1}^{2} / \sigma_{2}^{2} $} & $ \left( \frac{S_{1}^{2} / S_{2}^{2}}{F_{\alpha / 2} (n_{1} - 1, n_{2} - 1)}, \frac{S_{1}^{2} / S_{2}^{2}}{F_{1- \alpha / 2} (n_{1} - 1, n_{2} - 1)} \right) $ \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in a table cell for a math equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102411/line-break-in-a-table-cell-for-a-math-equation)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - Not a duplicate. It's true that both postings involve math material in a table cell. However, whereas the earlier posting required some explicit structuring, the new posting involves only inline math material and thus requires a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, the `c` column type does not allow automatic line breaks. (The same holds for the `l` and `r` column types.) Looking at the screenshot you posted, it's clear that some of the cells in columns 2 and 3 will have to be line-broken if the material is supposed to fit inside the text block. I suggest you switch from the `tabular` to the `tabularx` environment and apply centered versions of the `X` column type to columns 2 and 3, with column 3 three times as wide as column 2. As you may have guessed by now, the `X` column type allows line breaking. (I arrived at the 1:3 ratio of widths by eyeballing your screenshot; the guess turned out to be alright.)

Next, don't use `\left` and `\right` to enlarge the parentheses in the third column: line breaks are not allowed inside a `\left( ... \right)` construct. Instead, use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`. Finally, insert an `\allowbreak` directive after the comma in the long formula in the second row.

A separate comment: To give the tabular material a more open "look", consider omitting all vertical lines and employing fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Interval estimator for difference of means 
   and ratio of variance in two normal populations}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C 
    >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Unknown parameters} &
$ 1 - \alpha $ confidence interval \\
\midrule
$ \mu_1 - \mu_2 $ &
$ \sigma_1^{2} $, $ \sigma_2^{2} $ known &
$ \Bigl( \overline{X} - \overline{Y} - U_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}
            \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^{2}}{n_1} + \frac{\sigma_2^{2}}{n_2}},\
         \overline{X} - \overline{Y} + U_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}
            \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^{2}}{n_1} + \frac{\sigma_2^{2}}{n_2}} 
  \Bigr) $ \\
\addlinespace
$ \mu_1 - \mu_2 $  &
$ \sigma_1^{2} $, $ \sigma_2^{2} $ unknown,
but $ \sigma_1^{2} = \sigma_2^{2} $ &
$ \Bigl( \overline{X} - \overline{Y} - T_{\alpha/2} (n_1 + n_2 - 2)
             S_{\omega} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}},\ \allowbreak
         \overline{X} - \overline{Y} + T_{\alpha/2} (n_1 + n_2 - 2)
             S_{\omega} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}
  \Bigr) $ \\
\addlinespace
$ \sigma_1^{2} / \sigma_2^{2} $ & &
$ \Bigl( \frac{S_1^{2} / S_2^{2}}{F_{\alpha / 2} (n_1 - 1, n_2 - 1)},\ 
         \frac{S_1^{2} / S_2^{2}}{F_{1- \alpha / 2} (n_1 - 1, n_2 - 1)}
  \Bigr) $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```